# I can't find Theme editor in Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I can't find Theme editor..

I also try Tools ->
but There is no Android -> Theme editor

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> [Design app themes with Theme Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor)

Have you tried opening styles.xml ?

> Accessing the Theme Editor There are two ways to open the Theme
>   Editor:
>
> - From an open styles XML file, such as styles.xml, click Open editor near the top-right of the file window.
> - From the Tools menu, choose Theme Editor.

Comment: I tried opening the styles.xml file, but the editor window did not appear near the top-right of the file window. Also, Theme editor not appear in Tools menu.